# вывод из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, select, access

Есть таблица Клиент и Кредит (заемщик1 и заемщик1)

Почему у меня по ключу заемщик2 выводится фио заемщик 1-го??

```
SELECT Кредит.NДоговора, Кредит.ДатаДог, ФИО, ТипКредита, Кредит.Сумма,
       ТипГрафика.ТипГрафика, ДатаВыдачи, ДатаЗакрыт, Ставка, СтатусКредита, ФИО
FROM [Кредит], [ТипКредита], [ТипГрафика], [СтатусКредита], [Клиент] 
WHERE (Кредит.Заемщик1ID = Клиент.ID)
    AND (Кредит.ТипКредитаID = ТипКредита.ID)
    AND (Кредит.ТипГрафикаID = ТипГрафика.ID)" + "
    AND (Кредит.СтатусID = СтатусКредита.ID)
    AND (Кредит.Заемщик2ID = Клиент.ID)
```

Comment: Я отформатировал Ваш вопрос. Делайте код в таком виде и впредь - и люди к Вам потянутся! Проверьте ещё раз и откорректируйте Ваш вопрос. А также что это за `" + "` у Вас в WHERE?

Comment: Удивительно, что у вас вообще что то выводится. условия `(Кредит.Заемщик1ID = Клиент.ID) AND (Кредит.Заемщик2ID = Клиент.ID)` могут сработать только в случае если Заемщик1ID равен Заемщик2ID). Если вам нужны имена двух заемщиков, то надо два раза использовать таблицу с именами (разумеется давая ей разные алиасы)

Comment: ПОДСКАЖИТЕ КАК?